# viewpager2 setoffscreenpagelimit(3) not working

Tags: java, android, slider

Hi guys I want to make a slider with Viewpager2 that shows 3 element at the moment
and I want it to look like this
[how I want to my slider look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osBwe.png)
but my slider is look like this
[how my slider look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0OX9.png)
and here is my java code

```
public class ExplorerFragment extends Fragment {
    ViewPager2 usersAvatarSlider;
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.explorer_fragment, container, false);
        Find(v);
        initUsersAvatarSlider();
     return v;
    }
    void Find(View v) {
        usersAvatarSlider = v.findViewById(R.id.UserViewPager2);
    }
    void initUsersAvatarSlider() {
        UserAvatarSliderAdapter userAvatarSliderAdapter = new UserAvatarSliderAdapter();
        usersAvatarSlider.setAdapter(userAvatarSliderAdapter);
        usersAvatarSlider.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    }
}
```

as u see I'm using `usersAvatarSlider.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);`
but I don't know why it's not working

Answer (score 1):

`setOffscreenPageLimit()` does not set the element count. As per the docs:

> open fun setOffscreenPageLimit(limit: Int): Unit
>
> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
> current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
> limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

To set the element count, override `getItemCount()` in your adapter implementation `UserAvatarSliderAdapter`

Comment: I think you mean I need to do this
setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

and by the way my Item count code is this
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 20;
    }

Comment: I read your answer again and I found out you didn't understand my question
I want to show 3 slider item at the moment but it only show 1